# Prove an equality between ideals in $\mathbb{C}[x, y]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ideals

I have to prove that in $\mathbb{C}[x, y]$ we have the equality

$$ (x^3-x^2, x^2y-x^2, xy-y, y^2-y)=(x^2, y) \cap (x-1, y-1).$$

I have proven the inclusion $\subset$ proving that every generator of the LHS can be written as a linear combination both of elements of $(x^2, y)$ and of elements of $(x-1, y-1)$ (e.g.: $x^2y-x^2=x^2\cdot(y-1)$), but I am stuck with the reverse inclusion. Any suggestion?

Comment: Note that the ideals $I = (x^{2}, y)$ and $J = (x-1, y-1)$ are comaximal, since $y - (y-1) = 1$. Hence, $I \cap J = IJ$, since $(I+J)(I \cap J) \subset IJ$. Can you see how to proceed from here?

Comment: Well yes, now it is completely clear: the generators of $IJ$ are $x^2(x-1)=x^3-x^2, x^2(y-1)=x^2y-x^2, y(x-1)=xy-y$ and $y(y-1)=y^2-y$. And is this ideal radical?

Comment: This ideal is not radical. Indeed, the source of ''trouble'' is the generator $x^{2}$ of the ideal $I$. One can try to prove that something like (say) $x(x-1)$ is not in your ideal, but its square is. This might be difficult computationally, so there is a nice abstract approach here. Your ideal $I \cap J$ is radical if and only if the ring $\mathbb{C}[x, y]/(I \cap J)$ is reduced, i.e. has no nonzero nilpotents. But $\mathbb{C}[x, y]/(I \cap J) \cong \mathbb{C}[x, y]/I \times \mathbb{C}[x, y]/J \cong \mathbb{C}[x]/\langle x^{2} \rangle \times \mathbb{C}$ by the Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: As for radicality, we have that $(x^2, y)$ is not radical and $\sqrt{(x^2, y)}= (x, y)$, while $(x-1, y-1)$ should be prime and hence radical. Hence $\sqrt{(x^2, y) \cap (x-1, y-1)}=\sqrt{(x^2, y)} \cap \sqrt{(x-1, y-1)}=(x, y) \cap (x-1, y-1)$ so the answer is no. Is this correct?

Comment: Sorry, we were typing at the same time. Yes my argument is lacking the fact that $x^2-x$ is not in the ideal. Thank you!

Comment: @carciofo21: your argument looks nice as well! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Take an arbitrary element of the RHS and subtract linear combinations of the generators on the left hand side to simplify your element: the first and last generator on the LHS are enough to reduce your element to something of the form: $$ax^2+by+cxy+dx^2y,$$
as being an element of the RHS implies there is no constant or $\lambda x$ term.

Then the third generator gets rid of the $cxy$ term and the second gets rid of the $dx^2y$ term, leaving $$a'x^2+b'y.$$

Substituting in $x=1, y=1$ we get $0$ as we have an element of the RHS.
Thus $a'+b'=0$, so we are left with a scalar multiple of $x^2-y$.

But $$x^2-y=(x+1)(xy-y)-(x^2y-x^2)
$$

We conclude that any element of the RHS can be broken down to a linear combination of the 4 generators on the LHS.

Comment: Just spotted that the first comment on the OP contains a much slicker proof than this (+1 to comment).  Will leave this up for variety if no-one objects (also this method comes in handy a lot, both with commutative rings and non-commutative, so is worth having in one's tool-box).